# How can I extend edge features to add bleed to art designed without any?

Tags: automation, bleed

I have an image with some sharp linear/curved features and some noise and some other features near the edges. I want to enlarge the image and extend those features that reach the edge and span a significant distance into the interior of the image, but not repeat/extend features that do not.

In the before/after photo below I have extended a handful of linear features and a lot of colorful noise, but I did not extend or duplicate the numbers in the grey areas because they do not reach the original edges and don't span inwards from those edges. Are there tools that can automate this process?

[image: before and after showing image edge features extended]

Comment: In general, this is called [*inpainting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inpainting), but I'm not aware of a ready to use solution that allows you to be so specific.

Answer (score 1):

Comments and answers say "content aware". Here's an example of it

Make your canvas larger and add a new bottom layer. Fill it with a solid color. Here is used grey:

[image]

Flatten the image. Make a selection which contains at least one pixel row from the image and twice as wide area of the grey as you expect the new extended content. Press DEL and select deletion fill mode Content Aware:

[image]

The result:

[image]

The result is guessed by Photoshop. Unfortunately manual editing is still needed to fix wrong guesses and to remove the useless area.

Conclusion: Manual cloning along the continuing lines can be as fast.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is an automated process because you need to make some decisions. Sometimes scaling an image on the x-axis to gain 2 mm for the bleed, do not mean the same scaling will give you 2mm bleed on the y-axis.

Some images only need bleed on one edge, some on 2, 3 or 4.

I think you need to do it by hand.

Define the real minimum bleed you need. If the process is well controlled, and it is not for a booklet, you are fine with 1-2 mm.

But if its part of a booklet you probably need more. Around 2-5 mm. And also you need some safe zones, depending on the paper and the number of pages.

---

You have the option of faking the additional information on the image, which will be time-consuming, or you can simply scale the image to be cropped when cut.

---

As @joojaa comented, there is a feature on Ps called "Content aware" which might help you "inventing" some aditional texture of that zone of the image.

Comment: Content aware, could extend the toolset just isnt allhat optimized for the usecase

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one way to (partially) automate what you want to do. It wouldn't be as perfect a result as doing each extension by hand, but it would be fast and automatic. It would also require you to review each piece before printing (which you'd want to do anyway).

Assuming the bleed is the same for a number of pages (meaning, on the same edges of the page, and in the same amounts) you could carefully record yourself doing a generic stretch of a small portion of the edge, extending the canvas and adding noise as needed. You could then play out the action on the next page to test the results. If set up correctly the recorded actions could be played out on every page that needs extending into the bleed area.

This would, unfortunately, be limited to simple operations, like scaling a selection of pixels straight outward, but (as I said above) it would be automatic. Depending on how much is getting cut off after the print this may be sufficient. I have done something like this before when presented with art that needed bleed printing but wasn't set up correctly. A simple stretch and/or blending outward looks horrible on screen, but much (if not all) of it is cut after printing and looks fine.

If you go this route just be absolutely sure that you're only extending a few pixels of the edge of the image out into the bleed area and carefully review the pages afterward to see which of them requires a manual extension.

Outside of recording actions in Photoshop, I don't know of any other tools that could automate such a task.